# Make datatables work with turbolinks

Tags: javascript, datatable, turbolinks

I would like to use Turbolinks in my web application. However, i have some troubles with turbolinks and datatables.

Indeed, when i load my datatable for the first time, it generate the DOM for it and everythings is ok. But with turbolinks, the page is cached with the generated DOM and so when I change page and return on my datatable, all datatable feature doesn't works (paging, order, filter ...)

I think, reload the datatable when its DOM is already generated doesn't work, so i tried to destroy it before reload it : same problem

Here it's my datatable function :
[Datatable function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4St2Q.png)

And here the call to it : [call to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFoVB.png)

Have you ever met this problem and what can i do to resolve it ?

Thanks for your responses

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent duplicate wrappers on a jQuery DataTable when navigating back in the presence of Turbolinks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41070556/how-can-i-prevent-duplicate-wrappers-on-a-jquery-datatable-when-navigating-back)

Answer (score 2):

Do not initial the datetables again when return back from turbolink cache.

```js
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  "use strict";
  if ($("#users-table_wrapper").length == 0) {
    $('#users-table').DataTable();
  }
})
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Thanks!